# Inject String parameter into ViewModel from Compose using Koin

Tags: android, string, kotlin, dependency-injection, koin

As the title says I want to inject two string params into my ViewModel from my Compose Activity using Koin. And I don't want to create a Factory ViewModel.

I saw how to inject Objects but I'm confused when it comes to parameters. This was so simple using Dagger Hilt I feel stupid for asking this..Any tips please?

I call this from the compose activity

```
    val someViewModel: SnapshotViewModel by viewModel {
    parametersOf(displayName, securityName)
}
```

and in my Koin Module I do this but I get an error

Too many arguments for public constructor

```
val module = module {
single { params -> SnapshotViewModel(params.get<String>(), params.get<String>())}}
```

And here I try to inject them in my ViewModel

```
private val displayName: String by inject()
private val securityName: String by inject()
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to call `by inject()` in your property definitions. Either you pass the values via constructor or via injection

### Option 1:

- Create a constructor for your view model

```
class SnapshotViewModel(displayName: String, securityName: String)
```

- Then define property instance in the module

```
val module = module {
    single { params -> 
        SnapshotViewModel(params.get<String>(), params.get<String>())
    }
}
```

or

```
val module = module {
    single { (displayName: String, securityName: String) -> 
        SnapshotViewModel(displayName, securityName)
    }
}
```

### Option 2:

- Add the property definitions as follow, assuming your view model is tagged with `KoinComponent`

```
private val displayName: String
    get() = getKoin().getProperty("displayName", "defaulValue")
private val securityName: String 
    get() = getKoin().getProperty("securityName", "defaulValue")
```

- Then set the property values before initializing the view model. Depending where you set the value, you may need to tag the class with `KoinComponent` in order to have access to `getKoin()`

```
getKoin().setProperty("displayName", "Value")
getKoin().setProperty("securityName", "newValue")
```